# How can I update a custom top bar title component in React Native Navigation v2?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to update a custom topBar title component after it has already become visible. I've tried calling Navigation.mergeOptions and using passProps with no luck.

Initial options:

```
...
static options(passProps) {
  return {
    topBar: {
      title: {
        component: {
          id: "rn.MyCustomTopBar",
          name: "rn.MyCustomTopBar",
          alignment: "fill",
          passProps: {
            dynamicField: "Initial Value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
...
```

Using mergeOptions:

```
...
Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
  topBar: {
    title: {
      component: {
        passProps: {
          dynamicField: "New Value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
...
```

There appears to be a closed issue on GitHub regarding mergeOptions on custom components, https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3782, saying it will be resolved in #3030, however that issue does not have a milestone and hasn't had any activity since June. https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3030

If anyone can provide a work around and example on how this can be achieved it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom top bar can be updated by passing a reference back to the parent through passProps. The parent can then use the reference to call a function within the top bar that will change its state appropriately.

Parent component:

```
...
constructor() {
  super(props);
  Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);

  this._customTopBar = null;
}
...
componentDidMount() {
  Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
    topBar: {
      title: {
        component: {
          passProps: {
            passRef: ref => {
              this._customTopBar = ref;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
...
// called whenever custom title needs to be updated
this._customTopBar.updateState(...);
...
```

Custom component:

```
...
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.passRef(this);
}
...
updateState(...) {
  this.setState(...);
}
...
```

Note: This has not been tested on Android.